# .NET Core JWE: no "cty" header

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, bearer-token, jwe

I'm using the following code to issue my JWEs:

```cs
var signCreds = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:SigningKey"])), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
var encryptionCreds = new EncryptingCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Encryptionkey"])), SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128KW, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128CbcHmacSha256);

var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();


var jwtSecurityToken = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
  Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
  Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
  new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
  DateTime.UtcNow,
  expiresIn,
  DateTime.UtcNow,
  signCreds,
  encryptionCreds);
```

But it doesn't specify "cty" header of the token - just only alg, enc and typ. If I understand correctly, the header must be set for encrypted JWT so I have an issue while parsing the token in golang because of the headers absence.

I also tried the following ways to issue JWE:

```cs
var signCreds = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:SigningKey"])), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
var encryptionCreds = new EncryptingCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Encryptionkey"])), SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128KW, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128CbcHmacSha256);

var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var tokenDescriptor1 = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
  {
     Audience = "you",
     Issuer = "me",
     Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
     EncryptingCredentials = encryptionCreds
};

var tokenDescriptor2 = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
  {
     Audience = "you",
     Issuer = "me",
     Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
     EncryptingCredentials = encryptionCreds,
     SigningCredentials = signCreds
};

var tokenDescriptor3 = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
  {
     Audience = "you",
     Issuer = "me",
     Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
     EncryptingCredentials = encryptionCreds,
     SigningCredentials = signCreds,
     AdditionalHeaderClaims = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "cty", "JWT" } }
   };

var enc = handler.CreateEncodedJwt(tokenDescriptor1);
var encSigned = handler.CreateEncodedJwt(tokenDescriptor2);
var encSignedWithCty = handler.CreateEncodedJwt(tokenDescriptor3);
```

But have the same result:
[image]

I scanned the [library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet) but have not found the code that set the Cty header for token.

Maybe anyone knows what I missed or what is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a library [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1295)